# Open media vault NAS opening files in windows

Tags: networking, hard-drive, storage

I have a windows PC and was wondering if it is possible to have users in [Open media vault](http://www.openmediavault.org/) so that in the storage space there are folders allocated to specific users. So user1 would have a folder called user1 but if user1 tried to access user2's files then they would have to type the username and password for that account. 
I know that you can add a user but not sure if this possible. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like samba. Samba has user permissions per folder. Not sure how Open media vault handles those tho

Comment: Oh ok, I will have to do some more research